# How to pass a query in http GET method while using Next.JS 14 API route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http, next.js

While using Next.js 14 API route I'm passing a page in GET method to paginate what I fetch from my database. but upon trying to get the query from the request it's throwing a typescript error:

> Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request'.

```
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { page } = req.query;
    const pageSize = 5; // Number of videos to fetch per page

    const totalCount = await prismadb.video.count();
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / pageSize);

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize;

      // Fetch video IDs using a raw SQL query with random ordering and pagination
      const videoIds = await prismadb.$queryRaw<[{ id: number }]>`
      SELECT id FROM Video
      ORDER BY RANDOM()
      OFFSET ${startIndex} LIMIT ${pageSize}
    `;

    // Convert video IDs to strings
    const videoIdStrings = videoIds.map((videoId) => String(videoId.id));

    // Fetch the videos by the retrieved IDs
    const videos = await prismadb.video.findMany({
      take: pageSize,
      skip: startIndex,
      where: { id: { in: videoIdStrings } },
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ videos, totalPages });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('[GET_VIDEO_POST]', error);
    return new NextResponse('Internal Error', { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to get the page number from the request. How do I get over this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL and searchParams from there:

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) { // Note that it is a NextRequest here
  const page = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('page');
  ...
}
```

Comment: but is there a way to just pass it without the url? just as parameter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? How do you pass parameter to a GET request that are not in the URL???

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) { // Note that it is a NextRequest here
  const page = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('page');
  ...
}
```

The code above certainly works, but it can cause problems when building for production.

---

You can use the following alternative to avoid future problems. (tested Next js 14)

```
import { parse } from "url";

export const GET = async (req) => {
  try {
    const { query } = parse(req.url, true);
    const page = parseInt(query.page) || 1;
    const pageSize = parseInt(query.pageSize) || 20;
    ...
```